# Как зайти в обычный режиме в браузер через selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium

При использовании selenium webdriver окно браузера открывается в специальном режиме с надписью "Браузером управляет автоматизированное ПО". В нем не сохраняются файлы cookie. Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Answer (score 0):

В официальной документации есть пример для Python:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/support_packages/working_with_cookies/